# Adding a script to a game object dynamically and assigning values to its properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add a script/component to a game object and populate values in that script. The values for input come from the parent object as 'LineManagerProperty'. In the example below I want to add the 'LineManager' class to the 'Line' game object and assign the properties in 'LineManager'. If you look at the 'Line' class I add 'LineManagerProperty' so that it can appear in the unity inspector as values to pass into 'LineManager'. Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This is added here so that values can appear in inspector
    //These values will be passed into 'LineManager' when its created and added to 'Line' game object
    public LineManagerProperty LineManagerProperty;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //Add the 'LineManager' script and assign its properties
            gameObject.AddComponent<LineManager>().LineManagerProperty = new LineManagerProperty()
            {
                CollisionTag = LineManagerProperty.CollisionTag,
                MaxTimeDuration = LineManagerProperty.MaxTimeDuration,
                NumberOfHits = LineManagerProperty.NumberOfHits,
                Health = LineManagerProperty.Health
            };
        }
    }
}

public class LineManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineManagerProperty LineManagerProperty;

    //...
}

[Serializable]
public class LineManagerProperty
{
    public string CollisionTag;
    public float MaxTimeDuration;
    public float NumberOfHits;
}
```

Comment: I think you looking for copying component fields via reflection. Unity forum has couple answers http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458207/copy-a-component-at-runtime.html https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/copying-components-at-runtime-using-reflection.329800/

Answer (score 0):

Any public variables that you give a script in Unity will appear in the inspector and can be set from anywhere. In your case, move the variables from the `LineManagerProperty` into the `LineManager` script:

```
public class LineManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string CollisionTag;
    public float MaxTimeDuration;
    public float NumberOfHits;

    //...
}
```

Then to set your variables, just use the GameObject.

```
_line.CollisionTag = "";
_line.MaxTimeDuration = 0;
//.....
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The 'LineManager' script needs to be added dynamically and wont be editable from the inspector (because it wont be added there). If I add the properties to 'LineManager' like you suggest - I will have to create a prefab for it and assign the values through the prefab.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on the answer. When you add the `LineManager` component to your GameObject, in order to change the values through code, you need to get a reference to the component you added: `LineManager properties = gameobject.GetComponent<LineManager>();` Then you can assign the properties by doing `properties.CollisionTag = "";` etc. Nothing needs to be done through the inspector or prefabs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want, do you wanna see LineManager in inspector or not, or what, but i will try to help.  I guess you are creating some editor and you don't want to save LineManager in prefab.

Maybe it will give some idea for you, idk.

```
#define EDIT_MODE // if you delete this, code in EDIT_MODE fields will ignored and never compiled
using UnityEngine;
public class Line : MonoBehaviour {
    public LineManagerProperty lineManagerProperty;
#if EDIT_MODE
    LineManager lineManager;
#endif
    void Start() {
#if EDIT_MODE
        lineManager = new LineManager(lineManagerProperty);
#endif
    }

    void Update() {
#if EDIT_MODE
        lineManager.Update();// if you want to call something
#endif
    }
}

public class LineManager  {
   public LineManager(LineManagerProperty lmp) {
       LineManagerProperty = lmp;
   }

   public LineManagerProperty LineManagerProperty;

   public void Update() { // if you want to call something
   }
}
```

Comment: So I want the 'LineManager' properties to show in the inspector on the 'Line' object. The problem is that 'LineManager' inherits from 'MonoBehaviour' and this stops the inspector from showing the properties. That's why I have to create a separate 'LineManagerProperty' class without it inheriting from 'MonoBehaviour'.

Comment: So, you can try to create custom  inspector view for your script. [link](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector). idk.