# How to access the properties of a script when it is added to a instantiated object, and set the Transform in Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a portion of my script that Instantiates objects using a For loop:

C#

```
 enemyDragons2[i] = (Game Object) Instantiate(enemyDragonStandIn, 
 PlaceToSpawn -Vector3.forward  * 20.4f, Quaternion.identity);
```

I attach a script by doing this:

```
 enemyDragons2[i].AddComponent<SeekChase>();
```

The script does attach, but my SeekChase script takes a transform that I would usually drag into the inspector.

[image: Where I would drag a Transform into the Enemy slot in the Unity inspector.]

....But I would like to do this by script.

I know that I would have to do this:

```
 enemyDragons2[i].Get Component<SeekChase>().....properties.Name=..set...;
```

I have looked here:( and thought they were the solutions):

[Adding a script to a game object dynamically and assigning values to its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971560/adding-a-script-to-a-game-object-dynamically-and-assigning-values-to-its-propert)

and here:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/225030/instantiate-a-prefab-and-initialise-some-of-its-pr.html

I know that I can hard code the Transform by putting it into the SeekChase script, or by attaching the SeekChase script to the prefab with the Transform added manually in the inspector, but I would like to do this by code to make things more dynamic. (so I can use the same script for different enemies by changing the Transform).

How do I get inside the SeekChase script when it is added to a instantiated object, and set the Transform to the one I want in code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: AddComponent returns the added component. At that point you have access to all of its public members. If you don’t want to expose a setter for that transform, you could put a factory method in your EnemyDragon class, and that method would have access to all of EnemyDragons public/protected/private members.

Comment: *"but my SeekChase script takes a transform that I would usually drag into the inspector."* Hard to understand that. Post the `SeekChase` script and explain what you mean in that statement. Maybe a screenshot of how you are doing that now in the Editor

Comment: Picture added for clarification if needed.

Comment: What transform do you want to put in the SeekChase script? I will just cwharris'  answer to fix your issue when I get a reply

Comment: The Transform is any object/prefab that I put into the slot It is what is being chased All works as far as this. But I want to set the object/prefab not in the inspector manually, but by script/code, as in my original question above. Thanks

Comment: The object you are tracking does it exist in the scene? If yes,what's the name? If no then you have to instantiate that object if it is a prefab since you can't track a prefab

Comment: Yes the object, "Enemy" does exist in the scene. it could be any object in the scene though.

Comment: cwharri's code is fine. I modified the example in it to make it compatible with your original code and to also reflect everything you said in your comments and your edit. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will look this over and reply.

Comment: All is working. Glad that I was on the right track.Your answer was a little bit different than cwharris' answer, but he put me on the right track. In looking for help, I encountered GameObject.Find, but have seen that it is heavy if placed in the update. Luckily it is placed in the Start. Also in the "Set the enemy" part, I was missing was the ".transform", though I had nothing to "Set" because I had noting to find "Find"! I was wondering, can the GameObject.Find take a variable like ex. "Enemy[i]"? Or possibly do this:GameObject yourEnemy = Enemy[i]. But Again, Thanks Programmer and cwharris.

Answer (score 2):

You have a variable that is a type of Transform called `enemy` and you want to initialize that `enemy` variable with a transform of a GameObject in the scene named "Enemy".

From your screenshot and comments, below is what you should do:

Find the Enemy

```
GameObject yourEnemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy");
```

Set the enemy variable transform in the SeekChase script

```
enemyDragons2[i].GetComponent<SeekChase>().enemy = yourEnemy.transform;
```

With your other codes, it should look something like blow:

```
//Instantiate prefab
enemyDragons2[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemyDragonStandIn,
PlaceToSpawn - Vector3.forward * 20.4f, Quaternion.identity);

//Attach script
enemyDragons2[i].AddComponent<SeekChase>();

//Find the Enemy
GameObject yourEnemy = GameObject.Find("Enemy");

//Set the enemy
enemyDragons2[i].GetComponent<SeekChase>().enemy = yourEnemy.transform;
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. What is the C# version of your answer? I have been searching for a solution for days, so please be detailed in your example code. Thanks

Comment: Im currently on an airplane on my phone. Does this not work for you? What error are you getting?

Comment: I havent tried the code, but I just wanted the C# version for clarity since that is what I am using and know better. But if you are on a plane, I don't want to trouble you at the moment.

Comment: My answer is in C#, although there are some missing variable declarations, and I’ve used `...` in lieu of an actual value to assign. It’s just pseudo code, but if I understand your question correctly, it should work out with some adjustments for your specific use case.

Comment: Oh, and I wasn’t trying to be rude. I was just saying I don’t have access to my IDE right now.

Comment: Oh no problem. I saw "var" and I thought java script. I will try the code and reply... Kind of late here. Thanks Again.